# How to create a css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I would like to create a grid using css (flexbox or gird) but I'm not exactly sure how to achieve a desired effect. I want my grid to be flexible, so I can decide on the final look, that's why I want to create a classes for the sizes I need (take a look at screen below):
[image: grid]

So basically I need 4 classes so I can decide on width and height of the item.

I started a codepen (trying to use grid here), but I'm new to grid and can't achieve the result I need. I don't know how many rows there will be in final result, but I know for sure there will be 4 columns.

https://codepen.io/bordini/pen/OJBLbBK

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item grid-col-span-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.co/300" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.co/400" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.co/500" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.co/600" /></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.co/700" /></div>
</div>

.grid-col-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-row-span-2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create four new classes for each combination of width and height.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item grid-col-span-2 grid-row-span-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-2 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-1 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/300" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-1 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-1 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/500" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-1 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600" />
  </div>
  <div class="item grid-col-span-1 grid-row-span-1">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/700" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.grid-col-span-1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
}

.grid-col-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-row-span-1 {
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.grid-row-span-2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Now you can use the combination of the new classes to control the width and height of your grid items as required.

I hope this anwsers your question and also, are you using an CSS framework like Bootstrap or Tailwind?